# Facebook Graph API for comment - SEO

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook provides `Comments Box`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

The problem it the SEO as it use Iframe.

The solution is to use Graph Api:

> **How can I get an SEO boost from the comments left on my site?**
>
> The Facebook comments box is rendered in an iframe on your page, and most search engines will not crawl content within an iframe. However, you can access all the comments left on your site via the graph API as described above. Simply grab the comments from the API and render them in the body of your page behind the comments box. We recommend you cache the results, as pulling the comments from the graph API on each page load could slow down the rendering time of the page.

**But how can I query the API to get all messages for my page ?**

Answer (score 2):

It said it in the previous paragraph use `https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=`

For example

`https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments`

For your entire site you will need to pull the comments from each page individually.

Comment: so how can I integrate the iframe Box and make it seo friendly ?
Some blog use a (js)hidden div with comment/info from graph api
It is a correct approach ?